# Angular2+ with VS Code IntelliSense?

Tags: visual-studio-code

WebStorm just seems to work very nicely with how it can recognize and suggest methods & fields from within app.component.html. If I use {{ interpolation }} I get IntelliSense for available fields & methods, or if I use an undefined one, WebStorm will let me know. Also from within app.component.ts, if I have an unused field, I will also be aware.

VS Code on the other hand, seems completely oblivious to what is going on between app.component.ts <--> app.component.html.

Is there any way to fix it? Or is the product just not there yet. I've tried adding `"tslint.rulesDirectory": "./node_modules/codelyzer"` to settings.json.

Also, getting old angular autocompletion is quite frustrating. ng-if becomes `ng-if=""` instead of `*ngIf=""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) extension definitely seems to help, but doesn't allow me to see unused fields from within a component like WebStorm can. Better than nothing! Found it via. [this GitHub Issue comment](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript/issues/6508#issuecomment-268216843).